# Wie und wann setze ich ein Semikolon?

Tags: punctuation

Ein nicht mehr sehr häufig benutztes Satzzeichen ist das Semikolon:

## `;`

Wie wird ein Semikolon eingesetzt; welche stilistische Aussage bewirke ich damit?

Comment: Ist es Absicht, dass Du ein Semikolon in einer Frage nach dessen Verwendung benutzt? Ich bin verwirrt...

Comment: @musiKk: Ja ist Absicht, auch um ein Beispiel zu geben, was *ich* denke, wie man es einsetzen *könnte*.

Comment: Kann die Behauptung `Ein nicht mehr sehr häufig benutztes Satzzeichen ist das Semikolon` belegt werden? `Nicht mehr` bezieht sich auf welchen Zeitraum? Seit 2011? Seit dem 2. Weltkrieg? Seit Erfindung des Buchdrucks? Oder geht es kontinuierlich über die Jahrhunderte bergab?

Comment: Am Satzende mit Klammer. Zum Zwinkern.

Comment: Also **ich** benutze das Semikolon **andauernd**; und damit meine ich nicht Smileys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Das Semikolon verbindet im Deutschen zwei gleichrangige Sätze oder Wortgruppen. Es sollte dort verwendet werden, wo ein Komma als Trennung zu schwach wäre und ein Punkt zu stark.

Es lässt sich jedoch selten eindeutig festlegen, wann ein Semikolon gegenüber einem Komma oder einem Punkt zu verwenden ist. Die Setzung eines Semikolons liegt weitgehend im Ermessen des Autors.

Ein Semikolon hat grundsätzlich nebenordnende Funktion hat; es darf deshalb nie zwischen Haupt- und Nebensätzen stehen.

---

Die [amtliche deutsche Rechtschreibung (Fassung von 2006)](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/service/reform/) schreibt Folgendes vor:

> **§ 80** Mit dem Semikolon kann man gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Teilsätze oder Wortgruppen voneinander abgrenzen. Mit dem Semikolon drückt man einen höheren Grad der Abgrenzung aus als mit dem Komma und einen geringeren Grad der Abgrenzung als mit dem Punkt.

Beispiele für gleichrangige, vor allem auch längere Hauptsätze (mit Nebensatz):

- Im Hausflur war es still; ich drückte erwartungsvoll auf die Klingel.
- Meine Freundin hatte den Zug versäumt; deshalb kam sie eine halbe
  Stunde zu spät.
- Steffen wünscht sich schon lange einen Hund; aber seine Eltern dulden keine Tiere in der Wohnung.
- Die Angelegenheit ist erledigt; darum wollen wir nicht länger streiten.
- Wir müssen uns überlegen, mit welchem Zug wir fahren wollen; wenn wir den früheren Zug nehmen, müssen wir uns beeilen.

Beispiele zur Setzung des Semikolons bei gleichrangigen Wortgruppen gleicher Struktur in Aufzählungen:

- Unser Proviant bestand aus gedörrtem Fleisch, Speck und Rauchschinken; Ei- und Milchpulver; Reis, Nudeln und Grieß.

---

Im [Duden-Sprachratgeber steht](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/das-semikolon) als Ergänzung zu den bisher erwähnten Regeln:

> Eine starke Tendenz zum Semikolon besteht auch dann, wenn Sätze mit Konjunktionen oder Adverbien wie denn, doch, deshalb etc. angeschlossen werden: „Meine Freundin hatte den Zug versäumt; deshalb kam sie zu spät."

---

Man beginnt das erste Wort nach einem Semikolon übrigens nicht automatisch mit einem Großbuchstaben, sondern schreibt klein weiter wie beim Beistrich. Beim Doppelpunkt beginnt man den Satz wie einen normalen Satz mit einem Großbuchstaben, sofern es sich um einen vollständigen Satz handelt.

---

*Kleine Abschweifung vom Thema:* Wer Texte aus dem Griechischen übersetzt, muss sich bewusst sein, dass im Griechischen das Semikolon als Fragezeichen benutzt wird.

Comment: hmm. Aber bei welchem Satzkonstrukt wäre ein Komma zu "schwach" und ein Punkt zu "stark"? Ist das willkürlich?

Comment: Ich würde nicht sagen *willkürlich*; es sollte schon ein (z. B.) zeitlicher oder logischer Zusammenhang bestehen, der vielleicht mit einem Punkt nicht so klar zum Ausdruck käme. In vielen Fällen kann auch das Komma das Semikolon ersetzen. Es ist wirklich eine Feinheit.

Comment: @Takkat: Die Paragraphen vermitteln zwar einen durch und durch geregelten Eindruck, aber das ist alles irgendwie subjektiv ;) Wobei ich die Beispielsätze jetzt zum Teil gar nicht schlecht finde; beim Satz mit Steffens Hund hätte ich jedoch ein Komma gesetzt. In unseren Dokumentationen (z.B. Pflichtenhefte und ähnliches) findet sich das Semikolon häufig, um einen Satz nicht zu lang werden zu lassen, wenn die Zugehörigkeit stärker ist, als eine komplette Trennung durch Punkt suggerieren würde.

Comment: @OregonGhost In der amtlichen Rechtschreibung steht tatsächlich, dass sich die meisten ; mit , oder . ersetzen lassen; auch Gedankenstriche können manchmal sinnvoll sein.

Comment: @splattne: Das ist wohl so, ja - wobei man sich über die Wirkung eines Gedankenstriches im Klaren sein sollte ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost :-) Programmierer sollten übrigens nicht wahllos ; mit anderen Satzzeichen ersetzen.

Comment: @OregonGhost auf geht's! Lass' uns die Programmiersprachen-Gesetze umschreiben und dafür sorgen, dass am Ende eines statements ein Punkt statt dem Semikolon geschrieben wird!

Comment: @klyonrad: Ich weiß zwar nicht, wie du jetzt darauf kommst und was ich damit zu tun habe... Aber in Ruby kann man das Semikolon zum Beispiel schreiben oder auch nicht :)

Comment: @splattne Sehr gut. Aber ist nicht vielleicht unsere Verwendung (als Fragezeichen) älter? Ich kenne mich da nicht aus. Wenn ich früher echte altgriechische Texte las, stammten sie aus der Zeit vor der Kleinschrift; diese wurden erst sehr spät (9Jh?) kanonisiert.

Comment: Du vereinfachst; dass ein Strichpunkt zwischen Haupt- und Nebensatz stehen kann, sei hiermit bewiesen ;)

Answer (score 7):

It's more about [writing](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_05.htm) than German language

1- In complicated lists:

> In die Sitzung haben wir Professor Wilson, Universität Barnsley, Dr. Watson, Universität Barrow in Furness, Oberst Custard, Metropolitan Police, und Dr. Maple Syrup, Genie General, Universität Otago, Neuseeland.

**Better to write:** (notice that some commas are replaced by semicolons)

> In die Sitzung haben wir Professor Wilson, Universität Barnsley; Dr. Watson, Universität Barrow in Furness; Oberst Custard, Metropolitan Police, und Dr. Maple Syrup, Genie General, Universität Otago, Neuseeland.

In most lists a comma is enough to separate the items. In a complicated list like the one above, it is perfectly acceptable to use the semicolon to make the list more understandable.

2- Separating closely-related independent clauses:

> Gigili hat immer mit Licht (an)
>   geschlafen; er/sie hatte Angst vor der
>   Dunkelheit.

The two clauses here are closely connected but the link has not been made explicit. They could have been separated by a full stop.

> Gigili hat immer mit Licht (an)
>   geschlafen. er/sie hatte Angst vor der
>   Dunkelheit.

- If you are going to use a semicolon to connect two clauses, it is very important that the two clauses are both independent. That means that each clause has to be able to stand alone and make complete sense without the other. If either one cannot stand alone, a semi-colon **cannot** be used.
- Using the semicolon to separate the two clauses has allowed us to imply the relationship between the two without stating it explicitly. This can be quite a powerful tool in allowing/encouraging your reader to make implicit connections. As the reader is involved in the development of the idea, it may well be more persuasive than simply stating the causal relationship between the two clauses. *The decision as to whether to use a semicolon or to make the two clauses into separate sentences is one of style and, as such, is up to you the writer*. As with many punctuation marks, the semicolon is powerful and can give your writing a good deal more style and precision, but **it should not be over used**.

Comment: Best answer so far. :)

Answer (score 6):

Das Semikolon erzwingt eine längere "Denkpause" als ein Komma, schließt den vorangegangenen (Teil-)Satz aber im Gegensatz zum Punkt noch nicht ab. Im Allgemeinen sollte man es sehr sparsam einsetzen. Von der Wirkung finde ich es meist nur bei Prosa oder bei Reden passend, da es m.E.n. immer einen sehr getragenen Eindruck erweckt.

Eine Ausnahme sind die von splattne bereits erwähnten Aufzählungen in der Aufzählung, da dient das Semikolon nur dem Verständnis der Schachtelung. (Wie einfache und doppelte Gänsefüßchen bei geschachtelten Zitaten.) Dort hat es keine gesonderte Wirkung und kann bedenkenlos verwendet werden.