# Capital letter after a semi colon?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, typography

I've just learned today that one should use a capital letter after a colon in German if the second part of the sentence could be separated to make a sentence alone.

z. B.

> Ich habe Hunger: Ich habe heute noch nichts gegessen

(I'm guessing if I added *nämlich* to the second part, using a capital letter would be more controversial.)

Does this rule apply to semicolons too?

> Ich habe nichts gegessen; **ich** habe Hunger.

or

> Ich habe nichts gegessen; **Ich** habe Hunger.

I remember a literature teacher who would tell us that the partial disappearance of the semi-colon in writing was a shame, as it was a good balance between a comma which would bring a too weak separation and a full stop (period) which would be too much.

Comment: PS: Mahlzeit to everyone, I'm realizing my example are well chosen on a timely point of view!

Comment: Ha... indeed :). I don't know the rules for these cases but I would much prefer the non-capitalized version. Besides, I would not recommend using constructions like these at all. The semi-colon is pretty superfluous in German, and it trips me up when reading out loud. What am I supposed to think? Does the sentence end? Does it not end? What is that semi-colon trying to tell me? There is no need for something between a comma and a full stop, imho

Comment: @Emanuel how is that different from the use of semicolon in English or French? It's the same problem everywhere, it doesn't mean we should eradicate this punctuation for this reason alone.

Comment: Indeed not. I quite like and use them regularly, even though some people (authors, even) beg to differ: Kurt Vonnegut famously stated that semicolons represent _absolutely nothing. All they do is show you've been to college._ Ah, well.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre... I don't know about French but English uses the semi-colon MUCH more than German. I'm not used to reading and seeing it in German text which is probably why it irritates me. And I have written my fair share of texts in my life and never ever have I even used one. I'm just speaking about German though. It might have more sense in other languages. Each language has a different flow after all.

Comment: The semicolon is part of the German interpunction, and it is still being used; so why not use it too? See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/wie-und-wann-setze-ich-ein-semikolon

Comment: Der Doppelpunkt im erten Beispiel ist falsch; dort tut es ein einfacher Punkt. Ein Doppelpunkt steht bei der Einleitung wörtlicher Rede. Takkat sagte: "Jawoll!" Auch bei der Ankündigung einer Liste oder eines Beispiels findet man ihn oft, zum Beispiel: a) Rot b) Blau c) Grün.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if the phrase following a semicolon is a full sentence, the first (next) word is only capitalized if it would be on its own (because it's a name or a noun, say).

To answer your question, #1 is correct. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/semikolon) gives the following examples:

> Man kann nicht jede Frage nur mit Ja oder Nein beantworten; oft muss man etwas weiter ausholen. (Hier könnte statt des Semikolons auch ein Punkt oder ein Komma stehen.)
>
> Unser Proviant bestand aus gedörrtem Fleisch, Speck und Rauchschinken; Ei- und Milchpulver; Reis, Nudeln und Grieß. (Hier könnten statt der Semikolons auch Kommas stehen.)

Comment: I had a German correct me with a capital letter, and I thought the same way as you (and Duden for that matter!)