# Kann man ein Semikolon anstatt eines Kommas verwenden?

Tags: punctuation

Ich habe irgendwo im Internet gelesen, dass man ein Semikolon statt eines Kommas verwenden kann. Wenn ich mich nicht irre, kann man es so schreiben:

Wenn ich zwei Jahre in Deutschland bleibe; werde ich viel Deutsch lernen.

Kann ich es so in diesem Kontext schreiben?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/wie-und-wann-setze-ich-ein-semikolon

Answer (score 5):

Nein, die Verwendung eines Semikolons ist in dem Satz falsch. Außerdem muss danach klein weitergeschrieben werden (wie bereits von Hubert korrigiert wurde).

Im Deutschen wird das Semikolon spärlich verwendet. Das Semikolon wird durch [Paragraph §80](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf80.html) abgedeckt:

> Mit dem Semikolon kann man gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Teilsätze oder Wortgruppen voneinander abgrenzen. Mit dem Semikolon drückt man einen höheren Grad der Abgrenzung aus als mit dem Komma und einen geringeren Grad der Abgrenzung als mit dem Punkt.

Dabei sind zwei Fälle zu unterscheiden, wobei ich zweiten hier außen vorlasse. Der erste Fall ist:

> 1. gleichrangige, vor allem auch längere Hauptsätze (mit Nebensatz):
>
>    > Im Hausflur war es still; ich drückte erwartungsvoll auf die Klingel.

Betrachtet man das Beispiel, so würde man in der Regel einen Punkt erwarten oder einen mit der Konjunktion *und* abgetrennten zweiten Hauptsatz.

In deinem Fall liegen keine zwei Hauptsätze vor, daher kannst du kein Semikolon anwenden.

Comment: Und wieso lässt du den zweiten Fall außen vor?