# Wann darf man Sätze mit einem Semikolon trennen?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation

Ich habe mal gelernt, dass neben dem Punkt und dem Komma auch ein Semikolon Sätze auf eine bestimmte und logische Weise trennen kann.

Ein Punkt trennt ja Sätze mit abgeschlossenen Sinneseinheiten. Ein Komma mit inbegriffenden Sinneseinheiten. Soviel wissen wir. Ich kann mich nicht mehr direkt daran erinnern, aber ein Semikolon trennt doch dann Sätze mit zusammenhängender Bedeutung, oder?

> Ich mag meine Tochter; ich habe mir große Sorgen um sie gemacht, weil …

Irgendwie so kann ich mir das vorstellen, aber vllt. könnt ihr mich da noch einmal etwas anderem lehren.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/wie-und-wann-setze-ich-ein-semikolon

Answer (score 4):

Das beantworten die [offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf), § 80:

> Mit dem Semikolon kann man gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Teilsätze oder Wortgruppen voneinander abgrenzen. Mit dem Semikolon drückt man einen höheren Grad der Abgrenzung aus als mit dem Komma und einen geringeren Grad der Abgrenzung als mit dem Punkt.

Viel mehr gibt es dazu kaum zu sagen**;** man kann einen Strichpunkt setzen, wenn man das Gefühl hat, dass ein Punkt »zu sehr trennt« aber ein Komma »zu viel verbindet«. Die nachfolgenden Beispiele der Rechtschreibregeln zeigen nur auf, dass diese Möglichkeit sowohl zwischen Hauptsätzen als auch in Aufzählungen gegeben ist.

Es ist **nicht** erlaubt, einen Nebensatz von seinem zugehörigen Hauptsatz durch einen Strichpunkt zu trennen. Hierfür sind ausschließlich Kommas vorgesehen. Es **ist** allerdings erlaubt, eine Kombination aus Haupt- und Nebensatz von einem weiteren Hauptsatz (gegebenenfalls mit Nebensatz) mit einem Strichpunkt zu trennen.

> Ich sage dir, dass das so ist; wenn du mir nicht glaubst, musst du dir eben etwas anderes suchen.

Wie bei einigen Aspekten der Zeichensetzung ist es vor allem dem Schreiber oder der Schreiberin überlassen, ob der Strichpunkt an einer gegebenen Stelle das richtige Satzzeichen ist, oder nicht.